# SSH via PHP Exec

Tags: php, linux, ubuntu

I'm trying to build a deployment tool on PHP for a few sites on wpengine. I'm trying to connect via ssh but i'm getting the error:

Permissions 0755 for '/var/www/.ssh/id_rsa' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.

I've tried updating the permissions using chmod to 600 - which is successful but the prompt still show 0755...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

SSH uses a private list of valid keys. this list need to be read and write for the user.

The PHP script surely access to this list, and check the access to it.
755 say that is almost public. and it ts "too open"

Try to use in PHP the same users that own this file, and change the access to 700

Comment: Hi thanks - the SSH key is owned by www-data. The user that php runs on is also www-data.

Comment: So, Just only try to change the access to 700

Comment: That's the first thing that I did. It still shows 755?